# Hibernate StaleObjectStateException on an object I've only just retrieved

Tags: java, hibernate

In part of my code, I get an object from database via Hibernate, change one field and commit changes back

```
    session = HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
    Song song =SongCache.loadSongFromDatabase(session, songId);
    song.setLastModified(new Date(new File(song.getFilename()).lastModified() + 1));
    session.saveOrUpdate(song);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Song class is defined as , I also use Hibernate Envers and song is audited

```
/**
 * A Song (or sound recording)
 */
@Audited
@Entity
public class Song
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer recNo;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Basic
    private String filename;

    /**
     * Last Modified Date
     */
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModified;


    public Song(String file)
    {
        this.setFilename(file);
    }

    public Song()
    {

    }


    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String album;
  ......
}
```

But sometimes I get a StaleObjectStateException, I cant understand how this can happen

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.jthink.songlayer.Song#1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2359)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3010)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2908)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3237)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at com.jthink.buzikmusik.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.saveSongToFile(SongSaver.java:286)
    at com.jthink.buzikmusik.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.saveChanges(SongSaver.java:75)
    at com.jthink.buzikmusik.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.call(SongSaver.java:70)
    at com.jthink.buzikmusik.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.call(SongSaver.java:45)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Show us the source code and mapping of the entity.

Comment: Ive updated question with the key parts

Comment: Do you close the session after each transaction? Is there a chance that the session stays open, that the Song thus stays in the session cache, but that another thread modifies the same song in another session?

Comment: Ah, thankyou very much. I do always close the session, but in a finally() block and this can come after I have submitted a task for the same song to another executorservice. So if this task is started before my finally block() in the first task the problem can occur. If you want to change your comment to an answer I can mark it correct if you  like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do always close the session, but in a finally() block and this can come after I have submitted a task for the same song to another executorservice. So if this task is started before my finally block() in the first task the problem can occur, this was the problem.